# Inserting tab character into word document from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Word Template file with a table structure, 5 rows, 2 columns. The first column in each row has an identifier, template tag such as <PID>. Each tag is different, so 5 unique.

I open the template file and based on the data in the Excel sheet create a new word document based on the template with the template tags replaced by actual values.

I would like to "tab" over to the second column in the table instead of all of the text being in the first column.

Here is my current code for outputting the values pulled from the Excel sheet.

```
    With wrdDoc
        .Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<PNAME>", ReplaceWith:="<Project Name> " & strProjectName
        .Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<PID>", ReplaceWith:="<Project ID>=" & strProjectID
        .Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<DNAME>", ReplaceWith:="<Department Name>=" & strDepartmentName
        .Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<A>", ReplaceWith:="<Active>=" & strActive
        .Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<HO>", ReplaceWith:="<Head Office>=" & strHeadoffice
    End With
```

I have tried using chr(9) and vbTab but they just create a tab in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

If the insertion point is in a table cell, you can move to the next table cell using something like this:

```
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
```

That will move the cursor to the next cell.

Comment: Insertion point is not known, see original code, using Find/Replace

Comment: I don't think you can tab over to the next cell using find/replace.

Comment: It should be quite trivial to use .Find.Execute to find (rather than replace) each template tag in turn, replace it with whatever is appropriate, and then move the selection to the next column and insert some more text in that column (assuming that's what the OP wants, since it's not entirely clear). What you can't do is do it all in a single call to .Find.Execute.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you can use to write data to a table in Word, one of which builds on what you already have:

**1. Using Find.Execute**

If you must stick with the table in the template with the pre-defined tags, then you should work with a `Range` object for Find instead of using `Document.Content`. This lets you manipulate the "target position" in the document, similar to how you work with Ranges instead of targeting cells in a workbook from the workbook level.

```
Dim rngSearch as Word.Range
Set rngSearch = wrdDoc.Content
rngSearch.Find.Execute FindText:="<PNAME>", ReplaceWith:="<Project Name> " & strProjectName
'Move to next cell
rngSearch.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rngSearch.Text = "text for the second column"
rngSearch.Find.Execute FindText:="<PID>", ReplaceWith:="<Project ID>=" & strProjectID
'and repeat collapsing, assign text and Find.Execute
```

Code structure consideration: It might make sense to put the Find/Collapse/Text steps in a separate procedure (Sub). That would save repeating the three steps for every "tag":

```
  'code in main procedure
  Dim rngFind as Word.Range
  Set rngFind = wrdDoc.Content
  WriteToTagsInWordTable "<PNAME>", "<Project Name> " & strProjectName, 
                       "text in column two", rngFind
  WriteToTagsInWordTable "<PID>", "<Project Name>=" & strProjectID, 
                       "other text in column two", rngFind
  'and so on...

Sub WriteToTagsInWordTable(sFind as String, sReplace as String, _
                           sColTwo as String, ByRef rngSearch as Word.Range)

  rngSearch.Find.Execute FindText:=sFind, ReplaceWith:=sReplace
  'Move to next cell
  rngSearch.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rngSearch.Text = sColTwo
End Sub
```

**2. Using bookmarks**

Instead of using `Find` on string tags in the Word document, replace the tags with *Bookmarks* and target the bookmarks directly in your code. This should be faster. You can either insert additional bookmarks for the second column, or use the technique described above to move over to the next cell.

```
With wrdDoc
  .Bookmarks("PName").Range.Text = "<Project Name> " & strProjectName
  .Bookmarks("PNameInfo").Range.Text = "text for the second column"
End With
```

**3. Creating table in code**

It's usually most efficient to generate the in VBA code ,as a character-delimited string that's then assigned to the target `Range` (usually denoted by a `Bookmark`), and converted to a table. This is described in detail in my MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, the section "Populating Word Tables with Data".

Here's the relevant code from that article. It shows how to build a string for a multi-row, multi-column table from an array, pass the string to Word `Range` and convert it to a table.

```
Sub CreateTableFromString(ByRef rng As Word.Range, _
    ByRef adata() As Variant)
    Dim tbl As Word.Table

    rng.Text = BuildDataString(adata)
    Set tbl = rng.ConvertToTable(vbTab, _
        AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed, _
            DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord8TableBehavior)
End Sub

Function BuildDataString(aData() As Variant) As String
    Dim dataString As String
    Dim nrRow As Long, nrCol As Long

    For nrRow = 0 To UBound(aData, 1)
        For nrCol = 0 To UBound(aData, 2)
            dataString = dataString & aData(nrRow, nrCol)
            If nrCol < UBound(aData, 2) _
                Then dataString = dataString & vbTab
        Next nrCol
        If nrRow < UBound(aData, 1) _
            Then dataString = dataString & vbCr
    Next nrRow
    BuildDataString = dataString
End Function
```